# huggingface datasets convert a dataset to pandas and then convert it back

Tags: pandas, dataset, huggingface-datasets

I am following this [page](https://github.com/jlealtru/website_tutorials/blob/main/notebooks/Longformer%20with%20IMDB.ipynb). I loaded a dataset and converted it to Pandas dataframe and then converted back to a dataset. I was not able to match features and because of that datasets didnt match. How could I set features of the new dataset so that they match the old dataset?

```
import pandas as pd
import datasets
from transformers import LongformerTokenizerFast, LongformerForSequenceClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments, LongformerConfig
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support
from tqdm import tqdm
#import wandb
import os

train_data_s1, test_data_s1 = datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train[0:500]', 'test[0:500]'], 
                                             cache_dir='/media/data_files/github/website_tutorials/data')

print (type (train_data_s1))
  #<class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'> 



#converting to pandas - https://towardsdatascience.com/use-the-datasets-library-of-hugging-face-in-your-next-nlp-project-94e300cca850
print (type(train_data_s1))
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(train_data_s1)
print (type(df_pandas))


#<class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

from datasets import Dataset
import pandas as pd

dataset_from_pandas = Dataset.from_pandas(df_pandas)


dataset_from_pandas == train_data_s1
#False

#these match
print (train_data_s1[0])
print (dataset_from_pandas[0])

 {'text': 'I rented I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW from my video store because of all the controversy that surrounded it when it was first released in 1967. I also heard that at first it was seized by U.S. customs if it ever tried to enter this country, therefore being a fan of films considered "controversial" I really had to see this for myself.<br /><br />The plot is centered around a young Swedish drama student named Lena who wants to learn everything she can about life. In particular she wants to focus her attentions to making some sort of documentary on what the average Swede thought about certain political issues such as the Vietnam War and race issues in the United States. In between asking politicians and ordinary denizens of Stockholm about their opinions on politics, she has sex with her drama teacher, classmates, and married men.<br /><br />What kills me about I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW is that 40 years ago, this was considered pornographic. Really, the sex and nudity scenes are few and far between, even then it\'s not shot like some cheaply made porno. While my countrymen mind find it shocking, in reality sex and nudity are a major staple in Swedish cinema. Even Ingmar Bergman, arguably their answer to good old boy John Ford, had sex scenes in his films.<br /><br />I do commend the filmmakers for the fact that any sex shown in the film is shown for artistic purposes rather than just to shock people and make money to be shown in pornographic theaters in America. I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW is a good film for anyone wanting to study the meat and potatoes (no pun intended) of Swedish cinema. But really, this film doesn\'t have much of a plot.', 'label': 0}






#these dont match
print (train_data_s1.features)
print (dataset_from_pandas.features)

{'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'label': ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos'], names_file=None, id=None)}
{'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'label': Value(dtype='int64', id=None)}
```

####update 1---------------------

I modified my code as below to match features but still couldn't match two datasets

```
#https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-create-custom-classlabels/13650# "basic_sentiment holds values [-1,0,1]
from datasets import ClassLabel
dataset_from_pandas = dataset_from_pandas.cast_column("label", ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos'], names_file=None, id=None))
```

#these values match

```
print (train_data_s1[0])
print (dataset_from_pandas[0])
#{'text': 'I rented I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW from my video store because of all the controversy that surrounded it when it was first released in 1967. I also heard that at first it was seized by U.S. customs if it ever tried to enter this country, therefore being a fan of films considered "controversial" I really had to see this for myself.<br /><br />The plot is centered around a young Swedish drama student named Lena who wants to learn everything she can about life. In particular she wants to focus her attentions to making some sort of documentary on what the average Swede thought about certain political issues such as the Vietnam War and race issues in the United States. In between asking politicians and ordinary denizens of Stockholm about their opinions on politics, she has sex with her drama teacher, classmates, and married men.<br /><br />What kills me about I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW is that 40 years ago, this was considered pornographic. Really, the sex and nudity scenes are few and far between, even then it\'s not shot like some cheaply made porno. While my countrymen mind find it shocking, in reality sex and nudity are a major staple in Swedish cinema. Even Ingmar Bergman, arguably their answer to good old boy John Ford, had sex scenes in his films.<br /><br />I do commend the filmmakers for the fact that any sex shown in the film is shown for artistic purposes rather than just to shock people and make money to be shown in pornographic theaters in America. I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW is a good film for anyone wanting to study the meat and potatoes (no pun intended) of Swedish cinema. But really, this film doesn\'t have much of a plot.', 'label': 0}

#{'text': 'I rented I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW from my video store because of all the controversy that surrounded it when it was first released in 1967. I also heard that at first it was seized by U.S. customs if it ever tried to enter this country, therefore being a fan of films considered "controversial" I really had to see this for myself.<br /><br />The plot is centered around a young Swedish drama student named Lena who wants to learn everything she can about life. In particular she wants to focus her attentions to making some sort of documentary on what the average Swede thought about certain political issues such as the Vietnam War and race issues in the United States. In between asking politicians and ordinary denizens of Stockholm about their opinions on politics, she has sex with her drama teacher, classmates, and married men.<br /><br />What kills me about I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW is that 40 years ago, this was considered pornographic. Really, the sex and nudity scenes are few and far between, even then it\'s not shot like some cheaply made porno. While my countrymen mind find it shocking, in reality sex and nudity are a major staple in Swedish cinema. Even Ingmar Bergman, arguably their answer to good old boy John Ford, had sex scenes in his films.<br /><br />I do commend the filmmakers for the fact that any sex shown in the film is shown for artistic purposes rather than just to shock people and make money to be shown in pornographic theaters in America. I AM CURIOUS-YELLOW is a good film for anyone wanting to study the meat and potatoes (no pun intended) of Swedish cinema. But really, this film doesn\'t have much of a plot.', 'label': 0}
```

#features match too
`print (train_data_s1.features),`
`print (dataset_from_pandas.features)`

```
#{'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'label': ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos'], names_file=None, id=None)}
#{'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'label': ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos'], names_file=None, id=None)}
```

#But both datasets still don't match
`dataset_from_pandas == train_data_s1`

```
`#False`
```

Comment: this answers it - https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/huggingface-datasets-convert-a-dataset-to-pandas-and-then-convert-it-back/14708

Answer (score 13):

Use `df_pandas = train_data_s1.to_pandas()`,
[see the documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/process#export).

Comment: Strangely.. Not working.. even though the documentation shows it. ‍♂️ https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/process#export

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Found a "work around" well it's actually a documented way.

```
# convert output to pandas dataframe
dataset.set_format(type='pandas')

df = dataset['train'][:]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following:

```
import pandas as pd  # v1.3.5 
from datasets import load_dataset # v2.11.0

df = load_dataset('squad_v2')  # Loading the SQuAD dataset from huggingface.
pandas_data = pd.DataFrame(df['train'])
```